# How to change the email address in Forgot admin password template?

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates

Magento 3.2.1. In forgot admin password template it says support@example.com and in the sender it says "owner"

I know I can override the html, I just want to know how to change the variables, aren't those system wide variables? Where are they located? not in customer store -> customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is for Magento to use the "Customer Support" email identity when sending the forgot password email. The sender name and email for that identity can be changed from the admin at the following location:

*Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Store Email Addresses*

[image: System Configuration - Store Email Addresses]

Comment: Thank you, this this the right answer

Answer (score 2):

Took me a little while to track functionality down

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/User/Controller/Adminhtml/Auth/Forgotpassword.php#L117

Which traces through to this

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/80469a61e061abd0001c93497a6d92296b46496b/app/code/Magento/User/Model/Notificator.php#L94

```
/**
     * Send a notification.
     *
     * @param string $templateConfigId
     * @param array $templateVars
     * @param string $toEmail
     * @param string $toName
     * @throws MailException
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function sendNotification(
        string $templateConfigId,
        array $templateVars,
        string $toEmail,
        string $toName
    ): void {
        $transport = $this->transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->config->getValue($templateConfigId))
            ->setTemplateModel(BackendTemplate::class)
            ->setTemplateOptions([
                'area' => FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE,
                'store' => Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID
            ])
            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
            ->setFrom(
                $this->config->getValue('admin/emails/forgot_email_identity')
            )
            ->addTo($toEmail, $toName)
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
    }
```

So it's whatever sets this config value:

`admin/emails/forgot_email_identity`

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/80469a61e061abd0001c93497a6d92296b46496b/app/code/Magento/User/etc/config.xml#L14

So store > configuration > admin (or if it's missing that was the intention)

*Update*

Wasn't sure which variables

Hard coded array

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/80469a61e061abd0001c93497a6d92296b46496b/app/code/Magento/User/Model/Notificator.php#L109

Passed to template

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/f1da36945b71a002218a4047bc0d85c2252d3b5f/app/code/Magento/User/view/adminhtml/email/password_reset_confirmation.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  store > configuration > advanced > admin, I see the template for forgot password, but I don't  see where I can change those variable. Do you think they're not variables? They're hardcoded in the template? I don't think so, let me check

Comment: Wasnt sure what you meant by variables. I've Updated the answer with more detail.

Comment: strange i can't see support@example still, https://imgur.com/RaGNoBS like in the screenshot. I'll just modify the template.